# Flutter how to edit top of a container with ClipPath?

Tags: flutter

I have the following code in my flutter to edit a container:

```
      path.lineTo(x, size.height / 3);
      path.cubicTo(x + increment / 9, size.height / 2 + 100, x + increment,
          size.height, x + increment, size.height);
```

This results in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMYat.png)

However, the top part stays straight, how can I add curvyness to the top part too?

I tried using `path.moveTo`, but it resulted in the same shape.

Full code:

```
class WavyPages extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);
    var x = 0.0;
    var numberOfWaves = 1;
    var increment = size.width / numberOfWaves;

      path.lineTo(x, size.height / 3);
      path.cubicTo(x + increment / 9, size.height / 2 + 100, x + increment,size.height, x + increment, size.height);

    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.lineTo(0, 0);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(WavyPages oldClipper) => true;
}
```

Comment: Can you give proper code so I can test this on my end

Comment: @RisheekMittal I added the full ```CustomClipper``` code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the top part you can try my code:

```
class WavyPages extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = Path();
    var x = 0.0;
    var numberOfWaves = 1;
    var increment = size.width / numberOfWaves;
    path.moveTo(size.width, 0);
    path.cubicTo(size.width,0,size.width-increment,0,x,size.height / 2);
      
      path.cubicTo(0, size.height / 2 + 100, x + increment,size.height, x + increment, size.height);

    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.lineTo(0, 0);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(WavyPages oldClipper) => true;
}
```

And tell me if this is what you wanted...